# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16bb7fff8) crashing only physical devices and not in Simulator while initiating items from Struct

Tags: memory, swiftui, struct, crash, exc-bad-access

I have an issue with my app crashing on physical devices while it tries to initiate the my cards.
(simulator works fine)

I have a struct that basically initialises 61 cards like this:

```
extension HordeGameData {
 struct Cards {
        let SkeletonWarrior : MonsterCard = MonsterCard(id: 1,
                                                        name: "Skeleton Warrior",
                                                        image: "",
                                                        strength: 6,
                                                        life: 1,
                                                        type:  .Undead,
                                                        location: .Plains,,
                                                        images: .init(Normal: "SkeletonWarriorNormal", Attack: "SkeletonWarriorAttack", Defend: "SkeletonWarriorDefend", Hit: "SkeletonWarriorHit", Dead: "SkeletonWarriorDead"),
                                                        scaleFactor: 1.1,
                                                        description: "A weak skeleton fighter."
        )
        
        let SkeletonArcher : MonsterCard = MonsterCard(id: 2,
                                                       name: "Skeleton Archer",
                                                       image: "",
                                                       strength: 5,
                                                       fleeChance: 15,
                                                       giant: false,
                                                       type: .Undead,
                                                       location: .Plains,
                                                       images: .init(Normal: "SkeletonArcherNormal", Attack: "SkeletonArcherAttack", Defend: "SkeletonArcherDefend", Hit: "SkeletonArcherHit", Dead: "SkeletonArcherDead"),
                                                       scaleFactor: 1.1,
                                                       description: "A weak skeleton archer."
        )
... ... ...
```

if initiate more than 48 cards the game crashes with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, ..." on load.

Is there a better way to store and call these cards when needed in game, which does not consume as much memory (I believe from other threats that this is a memory error).

I currently use:

```
HordeGameData.Cards.init().MonsterName
```

I use the same method for all other card types as well, therefore I should change the structure of how I store an load data.

Comment: It's impossible to discuss the memory usage here (typically "bad access" indicates a threading problem). `MonsterName` does not exist in the code you've posted. Build a minimal example that crashes. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  I would expect you've made a mistake in whatever the `images` parameter is, but it could be many places completely unrelated to this code. Xcode includes a memory usage gauge, and you can also use Instruments to check the memory usage. Do you have any specific reason to believe your problem is memory usage?

Comment: That said, if you're creating many copies of `Cards`, and they all have several images in them, then yes, you could run out memory quickly. It completely depends on the rest of your code. Build the smallest thing you can that shows the problem. That process itself will generally show you the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. the app is very complex and it only crashes on physical devices and only if there I add more cards in exactly the Structs the I mentioned. I figured  out that the Structs are the issues, by reducing the number of cards it contains and then it would run without an issue.

 I found the solution, that allows me to add more cards by switching the Structs to Classes. Therefore not every time I need a card a full deck is initialized, but the memory is pointing to all cards at a single storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching the `Struct` to `Class` prevents excessive memory usage and allows to add more items.

`Classes` get only initiated once and are then referenced/pointed to for each call, while for each item in a `Struct` an individual memory space is generated for each initialisation.